# My android app doesn't load the app screen it just skips it to the main app screen?

Tags: java, android

I created my app from THE new boston tutorials but the problem is that the splash screen is not working. My app skips the splash screen and just start the MainActivity. I checked other questions and answers on StackOverflow but they didn't work. I am pasting my code here. Please check it and tell me whats the problem.

Here is my Splash screen layout file : splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/yoyo">"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now here is the Splash screen .java file : MyPage.java

```
package com.example.yoyo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPage extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
            sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }

            }

            }; timer.start();
        };

}
```

Now the Second screen which is my app screen. It is the layout file : activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameMe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/changeYou"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameMe"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Tell Me Your Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is the 2nd screen .java file: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yoyo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText nameMe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameMe);
    Button changeYou = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeYou);
    final TextView nameDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay);

    changeYou.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String  myName = nameMe.getText().toString();
        if (myName.contentEquals("pranav")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("Hey " + myName + ". Thanks for giving  Me Life. I love talking.");
        }else if (myName.contentEquals("harshit")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("Oye Chotte");
        }else if (myName.contentEquals("preety")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("Hello Mamma.");
        }else if (myName.contentEquals("ashok")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("Hello Papa");

        }else if (myName.contentEquals("akshit")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("Hello. Thanks for Using the app.");
        }else if(myName.contentEquals("clear")) {
            nameDisplay.setText("");
        }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

In the end here is the Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yoyo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name="com.example.yoyo.MyPage" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.yoyo.MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is log file :

03-19 19:43:07.039: E/dalvikvm-heap(24779): Out of memory on a 56819728-byte allocation.
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yoyo/com.example.yoyo.MyPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:718)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:382)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at com.example.yoyo.MyPage.onCreate(MyPage.java:14)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    ... 11 more
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    ... 23 more
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:586)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.View.(View.java:3564)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.View.(View.java:3493)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:469)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:242)
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779):    ... 26 more

Comment: It is not the right way of creating a splash screen use this tutorial to create a splash screen  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: @NARESHREDDY I think that the way i did is also right? Because it does the same thing if it worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change

```
 Intent newActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
 startActivity(newActivity);
```

to

```
 Intent newActivity = new Intent(MyPage.this , MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(newActivity);
```

***UPDATE:***

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(MyPage.this , MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    }, 3000);


public class MyPage extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.splash);
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(MyPage.this , MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    }, 3000);

    }
```

Change in your splash xml from

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/yoyo">"

  </RelativeLayout>
```

to

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yoyo">

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is a problem. Where you made a change (MyPage.this , MainActivity.this) there is a RED LINE. Under it. The quick fix cannot fix the problem. so any other option please?

Comment: Now you can check and enjoy

Comment: Intent newActivity = new Intent(MyPage.this , MainActivity.class);

Comment: thanks after typing the cmnt to piyush I realised that Vinayak1 has ".class" there. So i tried that. Now wait I am checking if this works

Comment: Have you comment your old code?? Have you import your Handler?

Comment: Now check this code again and import your handler also

Comment: I have imported Handler. Tried your code but again the same. I checked other question. They all tell to do some change in Manifest file. Is the problem there?]\

Comment: set the break point and debug the code and check in which line app got  stopped

Comment: 03-19 19:43:07.039: E/dalvikvm-heap(24779): Out of memory on a 56819728-byte allocation.
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 19:43:07.049: E/AndroidRuntime(24779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yoyo/com.example.yoyo.MyPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Comment: Means your yoyo image is too big to display on the screen so you got error. Just try with small resolution image in your splash xml file. then u willn't get error.You can set android:background="#ff0000" for testing. so ur app will not crash

Comment: Yes tell me because i m going now.

Comment: Ok nope. But what is ur prblm??

Comment: Its a right code you just need to start Activity as my first answer. Just nothing. Okay... Hope u will be understand. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
     finish();
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainPage.this,DashBordActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Use your class name because I have use my own activity name in code.